# Need to install Firefox browser on Hortonworks Sandbox virtual machine (HDP 2.4) running in Virtual Box 5.0.16

Tags: apache, hadoop, virtual-machine, virtualbox, hortonworks-data-platform

I am new to Hadoop and the Big Data world...

I have installed the Hortonworks Sandbox VM in Virtual Box.  It's working great...

Can someone tell me how to install Firefox within the VM?  I need it to use NIFI

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: What operating system are you hosting the VM with?

Comment: @cjackson Windows 10 64-bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing a browser on the VM and using it through VNC will typically be very slow. The best option is to set up an SSH Tunnel and do a local forward. If you use the PuTTy ssh client on windows then you can follow the following [instructions](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.60/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-ssh-portfwd) on setting up the local forward which will allow you to use your browser on the host operating system to connect to the NIFI instance running in your VM.